# How to get tax Rate details of sales order in Magento2 using rest api?

Tags: magento2, php, rest-api

I want to know the tax rate information of particular sales order.
I am fetching the sales order information from **Mangento2 rest API** using the following URL :

```
http://magentourl/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=" . $current_date . "&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=lteq
```

here I am getting the order details and I want to get the tax rate of related to this sales order.

I'm getting tax percentage but I want to know this percentage belongs to which tax type.

Please suggest me any solution if any one knows the answer or any idea?